# Python, working with lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have such list of tuples:

```
lst = [(10, u'1.15', u'1.15'), (5, 0, u'1.875'), (3, u'2.28', u'2.28')]
```

and I want to get the new one with just second and third element of each tuple, which not equal to the 0, in other words, I need something like:

```
new_lst = [u'1.15', u'1.15',u'1.875', u'2.28', u'2.28']
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new_lst = [x for t in lst for x in t[1:] if x != 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [x for y in lst for x in y[1:3] if x]
[u'1.15', u'1.15', u'1.875', u'2.28', u'2.28']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [(10, u'1.15', u'1.15'), (5, 0, u'1.875'), (3, u'2.28', u'2.28')]
>>> answer = []
>>> for tup in L:
...     answer.extend([i for i in tup[1:] if i])
...     
>>> answer
[u'1.15', u'1.15', u'1.875', u'2.28', u'2.28']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Strange -- this looks like you typed it in the interactive interpreter, but you obviously didn't, since the result is incorrect.  I'm really curious how this happened :)

Comment: This is exactly what the interpreter gives me. How do you suggest that this is wrong?

Comment: For me, it gives `[u'1.15', u'1.15', 0, u'1.875', u'2.28', u'2.28']`.

Comment: @Sven: you're right. I had to do an oldschool copy-paste (read and rewrite), and had missed that one